# configurations files with react? is that possible?

Tags: reactjs, config

I'm kinda new to react, knows the basics, not familiar with best practices.
We're building a generic system which we plan to install for various companies, and we have a demand that all urls / endpoints / outgoing links be configurable from the outside so we won't have to change code for each company.

I've been dealing with node services (bacjend) until now, so I put all those variables and configurations in a config.json, it sits on the server near the node.js service so it can pull configurations from it using `require` and all nice and good.

Now, I have to put out the same configurations for our react front-end. We want to be able to configure those variables once in a file, so that every client which pulls the index.js from our serves will get those defined already. I'm pretty sure the .json style won't work, as the index.js (or rather the bundled.js, the file after the webpack) will be served without running any code so it won't be able to pull those variables and might try to do so on the client.

I have no idea where to start... I read a bit about .env files, but again- it requires running some code to get them into environment and im not sure how is it gonna work.

I'd like to hear your opinions, what options do you think I have and what is the best practice to do it, if it is even possible to do what I want- pull all configurations from a single file in a single location.

Right now, for moving between environments (dev / staging / prod) we're using a URLs.js file which we change manually before building and deploying, but I want the option to do that without having to rerun webpack and redeploy.

Thanks alot!

Comment: I think you may want/need to "reconfigure" your endpoints/API surface to have each request also send some company code as part of the request, either in the path or as part of the payload.  Then the front-end is configured with that company code at build time from a build config and the API handles the company code switching. I think changing *some* company code per build may be unavoidable as even if your app pulled it's config it'd still need to know which one to pull.

Comment: I do not wish for it to decide on its own which configuration to pull. I want to have one source of truth, one file I can change manually on the server, and without having to rebuild my project the server will know to inject those parameters from this specific file before sending it to the client. Is there no way to intervene with the serving of the bundled.js and somehow inject those fields? maybe via webpack or something?